# Finding the highest number in a set of command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line

I'm just starting out with coding and tried to write a simple program in C to find the highest number in a set of command line arguments. The problem I'm having is that it always seems to think that the numbers given in the command line are crazy long. For example running './highest 4' gets the result 32765.

Replacing the code with "printf("%i %i %i\n", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);" shows that this is happening right off the bat. For example "./highest 1 2 3" outputs "32765 -975773016 32765" - and even more confusingly these values change each time I run the program. Anyway, I'm stumped. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int argv[])

{
    int highest = argv[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] > highest);
        {
            highest = argv[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", highest);
}
```

Comment: `argv[i]` is a pointer to *string*, not a number.

Comment: Turn on and **mind your compiler warnings**.

Comment: You can convert the string to a number with `strtol`, or `atoi`, or `sscanf`.

Comment: Forget `atoi` it provides zero error reporting and will happily return `0` without warning if you pass it the string `"cow"`. Checking the return of `sscanf()` at least provides a succeeded/failed indication and the preferred method would be `strtol()` which provides full error reporting capabilities.

Comment: You are printing the highest address (which will usually be the address of the last argument).  You're printing it badly — on 64-bit systems, `%i` expects to print a 32-bit value but addresses are 64-bit values.  ASLR (address space layout randomization) might account for the different values on each run.

Comment: You used an incorrect prototype for `main`. It should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or something equivalent, such as `char **argv` instead of `char *argv[]`). You cannot change the types of the arguments arbitrarily and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems pointed out in the comments:

- invalid declaration of `main()` See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) In a freestanding environment, the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. See: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)
- `argv` is a *array-of-pointers-to* `char` where the next pointer after the last valid argument is set to `NULL` as a sentinel. (meaning you can iterate over the pointers until you read `NULL`).

You cannot numerically compare the string arguments. (everything you read in C will be character data) You must convert the argument from a character string to a numeric value. You can convert to integer type or floating point type. As mentioned in the comment, for every conversion you must validate whether the conversion succeeded or failed, and then determine how you want to handle a failed-conversion.

Your choices for converting from string to number are to use `sscanf()` which provides a minimum success/failure indication by checking the return to see if it matches the number of conversions requested. You can also use the `strtol()`, `strtoul()`, `strtof()` and `strtod()` function to convert to `long`, `unsigned long`, `float` and `double`, respectively. These provide the best error detection capability, but also require a few additional lines of code to do it.<sup>1</sup>

A minimum example using `sscanf()` can be written as follows. If any arguments fail the conversion to `int`, a diagnostic is issued indicating what the argument was that failed, but otherwise it doesn't effect the logic to find the highest (`max`) of the arguments given.

You must also think about how you want to handle the case where the user provides no arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>     /* for INT_MIN */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int max = INT_MIN;  /* initialize max to lowest integer in range of int */
    
    if (argc == 1) {    /* validate args provided (recall argv[0] is program name) */
        fputs ("error: no arguments provided.\n"
                "usage: ./program number number [...]\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {                /* loop over all arguments */
        int n = 0;                                  /* int to hold arg conversion */
        if (sscanf (argv[i], "%d", &n) == 1) {      /* convert arg to int/validate */
            if (n > max)                            /* if good int, compare against max */
                max = n;                            /* update max if n is larger */
        }
        else    /* conversion failed */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: not an integer '%s'\n", argv[i]);
    }
    
    printf ("\nmax of arguments: %d\n", max);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

All integers provided:

```
$ ./bin/max_of_args 1 -5 10 3 12 2

max of arguments: 12
```

With arguments that are not integers:

```
$ ./bin/max_of_args 1 my -5 dog 10 has 3 fleas 12 bummer 2
error: not an integer 'my'
error: not an integer 'dog'
error: not an integer 'has'
error: not an integer 'fleas'
error: not an integer 'bummer'

max of arguments: 12
```

No arguments provided:

```
$ ./bin/max_of_args
error: no arguments provided.
usage: ./program number number [...]
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

*Footnotes:*

**1.** You can see the correct usage of `strtol()` at [man 3 strtol](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) that implementation is left to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was hugely helpful.